# PHP mysql_fetch_array return first member

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$url = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM dl LIMIT 1"));
$url = $url[0];
```

but I would rather use it as:

```
$url = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM dl LIMIT 1"))[0];
```

why do I get error for the second one because seems right syntax to me? Or do I miss something?

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in settings.php on line 52`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Also, don't use `@`. It's a bad coding habbit to just hide errors.

Comment: php 4 (mysql_) mixed with php5.4 short array syntax :(. It's like 15 years apart between features.. we're never getting rid of mysql_ at this rate

Comment: @MikeB I don't know if I'm looking forward to, or dread, the day that the current version of PHP doesn't have `mysql_` any more. Will we get people that are smart enough to switch to PDO/MySQLi with prepared statements or will everyone simply do a search/replace from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and keep all their insecure code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
$url = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM dl LIMIT 1"))[0];
```

isn't a valid php syntax(*): array dereferencing isn't supported in php version <= 5.3 (*)

As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

```
Example #7 Array dereferencing
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```

Second, don't use `mysql_*` as those functions are deprecated (use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead)

Comment: It is valid syntax, but only on versions > 5.4.

Comment: Yes, my script was written under PHP 5.4 and now I was testing it under PHP 5.3.3, that makes sense.

Comment: @BenFortune: I know it, I was integrating my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if you are fetching single row than use

```
mysql_fetch_row
```

instead of

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

it would be better if you switched to mysqli or pdo. The way you are trying to get the value of array is wrong in php

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed from `PHP` package soon. Better use `MySQLi` or `PDO` to feel safe... 
For more info about this topic see: [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Anyway. In this situation you can use `mysql_result`, with three params:

**result**:
Resource from `mysql_query()`

**row**: Number of Row, start at 0.

**field**: The name of the field, or index of that field in resultset.

```
$url = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM dl LIMIT 1"), 0, 'url');
```